# Classic ASP showing variable

Tags: asp-classic

I just want to show a result of a variable on a page and i am struggling

heres my code, the variable is in a table as you can see

thanks in advance

```
<tr><td><%
Dim sTest
sTest = "Monkey"
Response.Write("<p>" & sTest & "</p>")
%>
<p> This is Excel </p>
</td></tr>
```

Comment: What's the problem with your code? You didn't describe your problem, only your setup.

Comment: Are you trying to show this variable in a <tr>.. I don't see any <td> tag?

Comment: We need more input from you. What is the name of the page? What do you see in the browser?

Answer (score 5):

Save the below code as HelloWorld.asp. Open this page in a web browser. Tell us what you see.

(Don't put any html code or anything else)

```
<%
Dim sTest
sTest = "Hello World"
Response.Write(sTest)
Response.End
%>
```

Comment: @Jaden you were probably opening it directly, not as a web page hence what you saw.

Answer (score 4):

```
html code....
<p><%=sTest%></p>
html code....
```

Comment: @AndrewBarber I don't see the problem. `<%= %>` is legal syntax in Classic ASP.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understant exactly your code (This is Excel? ,/tr>? ) but:

```
<%
Dim sTest
sTest= "TEXT"

response.write "<table><tr><td>"

response.write sTest

response.write "</td></tr></table>"
%>
```

Will write "TEXT" in the only cell of the table.

EDIT: He was using .htm as file extension.

Comment: Hi Sorry for the lack of information, I actually want to do much more than that, when i try your code i get the same result - Nothing.  My whole page code is made up of your code plus <html> and <body> tags surrounding it, any idea what i am doing wrong?

Comment: <html>
<body>
<% Dim sTest sTest= "TEXT"  response.write "<table><tr><td>"  response.write sTest  response.write "</td></tr></table>" %>
</body>
</html>

Comment: It's OK, as far as I know the code is correct, is there any error showing? Is the file .asp? Do any other .asp pages work OK?

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code in a .asp file and it seems to be working... What problem are you facing? I have added border=1 to your code to show the table border...

```
<html> <body> 
<% 
        Dim sTest 
        sTest= "TEXT" 
        response.write("<table border='1'><tr><td>") 
        response.write (sTest)
        response.write ("</td></tr></table>") 
%> 
</body> </html>
```